# Xcode app is not full screen on ipad

Tags: xcode, ipad

When run my app on i get this result(black backgroud on both sides),I do not understand what the problem is?
Here is the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/05tnmb950zoz10j/IMG_0604.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The app is running as an iPhone app.

My guess is that you have only selected the iPhone as device under "Deployment Info". You can change it to iPad or Universal instead.

You will find "Deployment Info" under the "General" tab when you click on your project at the top of the Navigator.

Comment: You'r welcome. Remember to accept an answer by clicking the √ to the left if someone solves your problem.